# Can we get the Stats tab on the User+Tag Search?

Tags: feature-request, tags, statistics

When you click on the tags in a user profile, it now brings you to a [user + tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:95589+[sql]) (awesome new feature). Can there be a Stats tab for that tag on that page, like there is in `/questions/tagged/tag-name`?

As a possible additional feature, perhaps if coming from the user + tag search, it would show the searched user's stats if they don't make the top 20, instead of the viewer's own stats. For example, if you're looking at my C answers, I would show up at the bottom of each list, not you (if you belonged there...for all I know you're an epic C answerer).

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely like to see a stats tab on the user+tag page. It sort of confused me at first on the new page until I realized I was only looking at my stuff.

the idea about being able to see another user's stats for a particular tag (regardless of their position in the rankings) sounds like a pretty cool thing to see.

Answer (score 0):

Why is this necessary? **The current user always appears in the stats tab for any given tag.** It's forced in the query, assuming you're actually logged in.

I don't see what this would provide that you don't already get.

*Edit:* [This is no longer true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/bug-in-rep-statistics-display/18353#18353)

Comment: I think he is wanting to be able to see the OTHER user. Like...if he clicks on Joe Johnson and views stats for his tag, it would show his stats, even if Joe Johnson was not in the top 20.

Comment: TXI's right. Edited the question to make it more clear. Also, it's not necessary, but would be appreciated :)